# how to show values of three table with foreign key associated in table using entity framework c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

hello all i am new to entity and asp.net M.V.C  i am using entity framework code first approach with already made database i want to show three tables data in a table using inner join and confused how to do it

i have tried the following code given below

```
 public List<NewGroupRoles> GetAllGroups()
    {

        try
        {
            using(var p=new VMSDBContext())
            {
                var group = (from group_role in p.group_roles
                             join groups in p.groups on group_role.group_id equals groups.group_id
                             join roles in p.roles on group_role.roles_id equals roles.role_id
                             select new
                             {
                                 Id = group_role.group_roles_id,
                                 group_name = groups.group_name,
                                 group_role = roles.role_name
                             }).ToList();


            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<NewGroupRoles>();
        }
    }
```

i want to return it from a function in model

model classes are[ths class defines all the database entity classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UCHi.png)

[this a group table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5StR.png)

[this is group role class[][3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFYWA.png)

[role class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK0dB.png)

Comment: how to bind this to list to return it

Comment: What are your model classes where Entity is defined

Comment: EF is an ORM. You define entities and their *relations* and EF takes care of generating the JOINS.

Comment: You never *return* that list. If you want to return `NewGroupRoles` objects you should use `select new NewGroupRoles{...}` to create them. Right now you are creating anonymous types with `new {...}`

Comment: how to set values from database to newgrouproles object because it is not setting the specific values

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do work, which EF is supposed to do for you.

It looks like you have many-to-many relationship between the `groups` and `roles` tables. Why wouldn't you remove the `group_roles` class and just define navigation properties

```
public virtual IEnumerable<roles> roles { get; set; }
```

in `groups` model class and

```
public virtual IEnumerable<groups> groups { get; set; }
```

in `roles` model class

and get list of groups and roles somehow like this:

```
var groupRoles = p.groups.SelectMany(g=>g.roles, (g,r)=>new {Group = g.group_name, Role = r.role_name}).ToList();
```

Or if your use EF Core, which yet does not support many-to-many relationships without intermediate model class or just insist on having an intermediate class `group_roles` in your model, you can define two navigation properties in it, something like this:

```
public class group_roles
{
    [Key]
    public int group_roles_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("groups")]
    public int group_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("roles")]
    public int role_id { get; set; }

    public virtual groups group { get; set; }
    public virtual roles role { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query is just

```
var groupRoles = p.group_roles.Select(gr=> new {gr.group_roles_id, Group=gr.group.group_name, Role=gr.role.role_name).ToList();
```

Comment: if i remove group roles table where i store group with their roles?

Comment: @Hafizumer in database. In your SQL database you should have a group_roles table with corresponding foreign keys. But if you are using EF .NET (not Core) you must not have an intermediate table in the model. Even if you use code first, EF will create this table for you and use it behind the scenes. In EF Core the group_roles table must be present in the model, but still you should use navigation properties instead of self-designed complicated multitable queries.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected an answer a bit. Remove not group_roles table, but group_roles class from your data model

Answer (score -2):

Use this as you need to have new object while selecting

```
public List<NewGroupRoles> GetAllGroups()
            {

                try
                {
                    using(var p=new VMSDBContext())
                    {
                        var group = (from group_role in p.group_roles
                                     join groups in p.groups on group_role.group_id equals groups.group_id
                                     join roles in p.roles on group_role.roles_id equals roles.role_id
                                     select new NewGroupRoles()
                                     {
                                         Id = group_role.group_roles_id,
                                         group_name = groups.group_name,
                                         group_role = roles.role_name
                                     }).ToList();


                    }

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return new List<NewGroupRoles>();
                }
       return group;
}
```

Comment: This looks almost identical to the questions code. What was the change? Code only answers *may* be acceptable if they are obvious but this answer is not

Comment: Its not identical as i used  select new NewGroupRoles() while selecting

Comment: @AbhishekSharma It was identical when you posted your answer before editing.

Comment: How is that supposed to help? Write that in the question. Don't make people guess. BTW nothing will help if you don't *return* the results

Comment: Ofcourse you need to return group over here.Its basic thing.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma *your answer* though doesn't do that. Please check [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you want to say that the OP should create objects of the correct type and return them, *write* it. Don't expect people to diff your answer with the original to understand what you mean